# Using the unpacking operator '*' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have encountered some weird behaviour using the unpacking operator '*' in Python.

```py
L = [1,2,3]  
print(*L if len(L)<=2 else f"{L[0]}-{L[-1]}")
```

Running the above code I was expecting the output "1-3" but instead i get "1 - 3". Am I using the '*'-operator wrong? Or are my if/else-statements wrong?

I tried changing the "**L" to "L" which resolved the problem. This, however messes up the output when len(L)<3. Changing the "L*" to "L" fixes the problem. But since len(L) is not <=2 this should not affect the output, right?

Comment: Workaround: `print(*L if len(L)<=2 else [f"{L[0]}-{L[-1]}"])`

Comment: @bereal explained the reasoning behind the extra spaces. Building on that answer - you can use something like this `print(*L if len(L)<=2 else f"{L[0]}-{L[-1]}", sep="")`

Comment: @Vini, that runs the numbers together in the len==2 case.  How about `print(*L[::max(1, len(L)-1)], sep="-" if len(L) > 2 else " ")`?

Answer (score 3):

This expression is parsed as

```
print(*(L if len(L)<=2 else f"{L[0]}-{L[-1]}"))
```

which, for the given `L`, is equivalent to:

```
print(*'1-3')
```

which is in turn the same as:

```
print('1', '-', '3')
```

And that's where the spaces are coming from.

Comment: God, unpacking can be really weird sometimes.